# extracting subset of data from a list of dict based on keys

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Here is my data structure - it's a list of dictionaries of movies information with keys like title, year, genre.

Here's just a small sample.

```
{'Action': [{'title': 'They Live',
   'year': 1988,
   'genres': ['Action', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi'],
   'duration': 94,
   'directors': ['John Carpenter'],
   'actors': ['Roddy Piper', 'Keith David', 'Meg Foster'],
   'rating': 7.3},
  {'title': 'Ultra Warrior',
   'year': 1990,
   'genres': ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Sci-Fi'],
   'duration': 81,
   'directors': ['Augusto Tamayo San Román', 'Kevin Tent'],
   'actors': ['Dack Rambo',
    'Clare Beresford',
    'Meshach Taylor',
    'Mark Bringelson'],
   'rating': 1.9},
  {'title': 'Kick-Ass 2',
   'year': 2013,
   'genres': ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Crime'],
   'duration': 103,
   'directors': ['Jeff Wadlow'],
   'actors': ['Aaron Taylor-Johnson', 'Chloë Grace Moretz'],
   'rating': 6.5},.... 
'Drama': [{'title': 'Dirty Beautiful',
   'year': 2015,
   'genres': ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance'],
   'duration': 95,
   'directors': ['Tim Bartell'],
   'actors': ['Ricky Mabe', 'Jordan Monaghan', 'Conor Leslie', 'Darin Heames'],
   'rating': 5.5},
  {'title': 'Honeydripper',
   'year': 2007,
   'genres': ['Crime', 'Drama', 'History', 'Action', 'Adventure'],
   'duration': 124,
   'directors': ['John Sayles', 'Wachowskis'],
   'actors': ['Danny Glover', 'LisaGay Hamilton', 'Yaya DaCosta'],
   'rating': 6.6}, }
```

Based on info about directors (from key: directors) I need to pull a subset of data. The question is - what are the titles of the movies directed by the Wachowskis that contain both 'Action' and 'Adventure' in their genre? The output should be a list.

Thank you so much for any help!!

Comment: Hi! What solutions have you tried? Do you have reasons why they don’t work?

Comment: Tip: You’ll want to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) with an `if`-condition

Answer (score 1):

You could try a list comprehension:

```
action_adventure_wachowskis_movies = [
   movie['title']
   for genre in data
   for movie in data[genre]
   if 'Wachowskis' in movie['directors'] and
      {'Action', 'Adventure'}.issubset(movie['genres'])
]
print(action_adventure_wachowskis_movies)
```

**Output:**

```
['Honeydripper']
```

Comment: You could replace `for genre in data
   for movie in data[genre]` with `for genre in data.values() for movie in genre`

Comment: I considered this but I thought that using `for genre in data.values()` wasn't semantically correct. #HardestProblemInComputerScienceIsNamingThings.

Comment: Fair point. Maybe `for group in data.values()`. Since genres are already listed in subfield `'genres'`, and since your algorithm iterates over all films without using the fact that they were grouped by genre, it doesn't actually matter what criterion is used for grouping.